# C# function does not stop after returning the value

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have this function, that should find full filename from given root directory and file name.

```
        static string WalkDirectoryTree(DirectoryInfo root, string fileName)
        {
            FileInfo[] files = null;
            DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;
            files = root.GetFiles("*.*");
            string fullFileName = "";
            string rnd = "";

            if (files != null)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo file in files)
                {
                    if(file.Name == fileName)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Success!");
                        fullFileName = file.FullName;
                        rnd = file.Name;
                        return fullFileName;
                    }
                }
                subDirs = root.GetDirectories();
                foreach (DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirs)
                {
                    if (rnd == fileName)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        WalkDirectoryTree(dirInfo, fileName);
                    }
                }
            }
            return fullFileName;
        }
```

I was looking how this code executes with help of breakpoints. It finds the searched file name and it enters that if statement (below)

```
if(file.Name == fileName)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Success!");
                        fullFileName = file.FullName;
                        rnd = file.Name;
                        return fullFileName;
                    }
```

By following along execution I also found out, that it does execute the return step in if statement above, and after that goes straight to the end of the function, but then, it continues to execute that function again and again, until it has gone through all the subdirectories in given root directory. And obviously, it overwrites returning value and it is not what this function was intended to do.

Can someone spot the problem and suggest any solution to this?

Comment: You've discovered recursive functions. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: when calling `WalkDirectoryTree(dirInfo, fileName);` you don't do anything with the result. If that recursive call found what you're looking for, there should be a `return` there

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger to see what's happening

Comment: @StenPetrov: OP clearly has done so and is mystified by the fact that `return` doesn't leave the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations, you've found a tree-walking problem which may be better served by an explicit stack than recursive function calls.

While it is possible to inspect the return value of recursive calls as several people have commented, there's a price associated with that.  Here's a better alternative:

```
    static string WalkDirectoryTree(DirectoryInfo root, string fileName)
    {
        var to_process = new Stack<DirectoryInfo>();
        to_process.Push(root);

        while (to_process.TryPop(out var dir))
        {
            foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles(filename))
            {
                if(file.Name == fileName)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Success!");
                    return file.FullName;
                }
            }

            foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dir.GetDirectories())
            {
                to_process.Push(subdir);
            }
        }
        return null; // no matches
    }
```

This will do a depth-first search just like the recursive version, but it won't use multiple frames on the call stack, so the first match can return immediately to the original caller, while the recursive version returned to itself one directory level up.  Do note that the search will go in the reverse order that subdirectories are returned from `GetDirectories()` due to using a LIFO stack... if important this can be changed by reversing the `GetDirectories()` results before looping and pushing.

I've also changed the filespec passed to `dir.GetFiles` from `*.*` to `filename`, since you aren't interested in all files in the directory.  I didn't take out the case-sensitive string equality test, but you probably don't want that either.

---

Still, it's a good idea to learn to write and debug recursive code.  When stepping through in the debugger, make sure to have your "Call Stack" debugger window open, and **when you hit a `return` statement watch that Call Stack window carefully**.

---

Finally, this recursive search is built into the framework.  Simply

```
return root.EnumerateFiles(fileName, SearchOption.AllDirectories).FirstOrDefault();
```

is sufficient to perform a recursive search that stops at the first match (unlike passing the same `SearchOption.AllDirectories` to `GetFiles()` which will wastefully find every match in the whole directory tree)

Really, the only reason for writing this yourself, apart from the experience gained, is to avoid the pitfall mentioned in the documentation:

> If you choose `AllDirectories` in your search and the directory structure contains a link that creates a loop, the search operation enters an infinite loop.

When writing the tree walk yourself, it's possible to do something about this problem (although the improved code presented above still ignores this situation)

Comment: "While it is possible to inspect the return value of recursive calls as several people have commented, there's a price associated with that." - What do you mean?

Comment: @Enigmativity: Function calls aren't free, using recursion requires setting up and destroying a frame on the call stack for every tree node visited.  The call stack has to maintain quite a lot more information (return address, parameters, local variables, exception-handling metadata) than the explicit `to_process` stack data structure I propose.... and in my version when I find the result I can just abandon the data structure (thanks garbage collector!), while the call stack has to be unwound one frame at a time, resuming execution in the caller each time.

Comment: I'm with you on all that. It's the "While it is possible to inspect the return value of recursive calls" part I was unsure of.

Comment: @Enigmativity: In addition to the work the computer does unwinding the call stack, there's also a human cost in terms of needing to write the code to check the return value and then re-return it.

Comment: Thank you @BenVoigt. This helped a lot! Unlike all the other comments just pointing out, that I'm doing recursion :)

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, you're calling a recursive function so you're getting a lot of calls to `WalkDirectoryTree` and each one is returning one and only one value, but because of the many calls it appears like the one call is still going.

I did want to give you an alternative that might provide you with some food-for-thought on how to tackle this kind of problem in the future.

The key thing that you're recursing is the traversal of your directory structure. If you start with a method that just does that.

```
static IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> WalkDirectoryTree(DirectoryInfo root)
{
    yield return root;
    foreach (var di1 in root.GetDirectories())
        foreach (var di2 in WalkDirectoryTree(di1))
            yield return di2;
}
```

That just returns all of the directories starting with `root` and recursing down the directory structure until it runs out of directories. It's lazily evaluated so it only returns as many directories as you ask for. That's useful when you go looking for your file as it will stop listing directories once it finds your file.

Now the search function is simple and non-recursive.

```
static string FindTheFile(DirectoryInfo root, string fileName)
{
    foreach (var di in WalkDirectoryTree(root))
        foreach (var fi in di.GetFiles())
            if (fi.Name == fileName)
                return fi.FullName;
    return String.Empty;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your call to `WalktDirecotryTree`.  You don't check it's return value, so you need to bail if that returns what you wanted.